# What does the following negative kernel value mean?

Tags: kernel

What does the following negative kernel value mean ?

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From kernel documentation negative value make no sense:

> rp_filter - INTEGER
>
> ```
>     0 - No source validation.
>     1 - Strict mode as defined in RFC3704 Strict Reverse Path 
>         Each incoming packet is tested against the FIB and if the interface
>         is not the best reverse path the packet check will fail.
>         By default failed packets are discarded.
>     2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path 
>         Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB
>         and if the source address is not reachable via any interface
>         the packet check will fail.
> ```

So it is possible the minus is a mistake